# Oracle: Many to Many: Requires two Foreign Key Constraints?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

Im very new to SQL and i tried to create a many to many relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE HOUSE_USER
(
    USER_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    USER_EMAIL VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    USER_PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT USER_PK PRIMARY KEY(USER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT PROFILE_FK FOREIGN KEY(PROFILE_ID) REFERENCES HOUSE_PROFILE(PROFILE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE HOUSE_USER_GROUPE
(
    USER_GROUPE_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    USER_GROUPE_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT USER_GROUPE_PK PRIMARY KEY(USER_GROUPE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE HOUSE_USER_USER_GROUPE
(
    USER_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    USER_GROUPE_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT USER_USER_GROUPE_PK PRIMARY KEY(USER_ID, USER_GROUPE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT USER_FK FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES HOUSE_USER(USER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT USER_GROUPE_FK FOREIGN KEY(USER_GROUPE_ID) REFERENCES HOUSE_USER_GROUPE(USER_GROUPE_ID)
);
```

I need to ask now if these two constraints:

```
CONSTRAINT USER_FK FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES HOUSE_USER(USER_ID),
CONSTRAINT USER_GROUPE_FK FOREIGN KEY(USER_GROUPE_ID) REFERENCES
```

are neccessary or not. I ask because i have another many to many relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE HOUSE_USER_GROUPE
(
    USER_GROUPE_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    USER_GROUPE_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT USER_GROUPE_PK PRIMARY KEY(USER_GROUPE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE HOUSE_ACCESSR
(
    ACCESSR_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    ACCESSR_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ACCESSR_PK PRIMARY KEY(ACCESSR_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE HOUSE_USER_GROUPE_ACCESR
(
    USER_GROUPE_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    ACCESSR_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT USER_GROUPE_ACCESSR_PK PRIMARY KEY(USER_GROUPE_ID, ACCESSR_ID),
    CONSTRAINT USER_GROUPE_FK FOREIGN KEY(USER_GROUPE_ID) REFERENCES HOUSE_USER_GROUPE(USER_GROUPE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT ACCESSR_FK FOREIGN KEY(ACCESSR_ID) REFERENCES HOUSE_ACCESSR(ACCESSR_ID)
);
```

I cant create the second many to many table because i already used the constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT USER_GROUPE_FK FOREIGN KEY(USER_GROUPE_ID) REFERENCES HOUSE_USER_GROUPE(USER_GROUPE_ID),
```

I could just rename it but because of that error:

> ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint

I just was wondering if these constraints are mandatory.

Comment: Im just confused with your table and mapping but any way if you need all mapping it is possible by giving a seperate constraint name for the last many  to many table

Comment: what exactly is confusing you? As im new to sql i guess there are much better ways to do what i want to do. I basically just have a user table and a user_groups table and one user can have multiplise user_groups so it is a many to many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yes*, you should create the foreign key constrain on both tables.

The foreign key constraints are there to maintain referential integrity; ensuring that you can't insert values that don't exist in the parent table.

If you don't add the constraint to `HOUSE_USER_GROUPE_ACCESR` then you don't get that protection in that table.  And you *should* want that protection *everywhere*.

Your only apparent mistake is that the constraint names are identical to each other.  I traditionally either include No Name *(letting Oracle decide on the name, because I never refer to the constraint by name)* or use a format something like `fk_<table>_<field>`.

Comment: ok so what happens if i just write: `FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES HOUSE_USER(USER_ID),` instead of `CONSTRAINT USER_FK FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES HOUSE_USER(USER_ID),` i will not have the protection?

Comment: @Mulgard - The `name` of a constraint doesn't matter in terms of the constraint existing.  Missing out the name in that statement just means `Oracle, please choose a name for me`, nothing to do with whether the constraint exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the constraints.. create the second constraints with another name.

Comment: Can you explain why? I tried to build the schema without the keyword CONSTRAINT and the variable name. So i forexample just wrote `FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES HOUSE_USER(USERID)` and the schema could be built.

Comment: 100% that time oracle itself will choose a name for it..go and check the script created you can see a name there